# Getting ids which belongs to a particular category and also does not belong to another category

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose my table is as follows,

```
id  category
1   a
5   a
5   b
6   a
6   c
7   a
7   d
```

I want to get the IDs which belong to category A, but does not belong to category b. My output should be,

```
id  category
1   a
6   a
6   c
7   a
7   d
```

How do we do this in PostgreSQL?

Thanks

Comment: What you have tried? And why your id field has null values? It makes no sense.

Comment: @JorgeCampos Sorry about that.. I just edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select t.id, x.category 
from tablename x 
left join (
select distinct id from tablename where category <> 'b'
except
select distinct id from tablename where category = 'b') t
on x.id = t.id
```

The `except` operator can be used here.

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot !